# How to find quicktime version

Tags: .net, vb.net, quicktime

I need to find the installed quicktime version programatically. Previously i was checking the registry entry `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall` for quicktime.
But in the latest update of quicktime (Version 7.5) it doesn't work.

I found this piece of code in vbscript but cannot figure out how to do this in vb.net.

```
strComputer = "."

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")

Set colItems = objWMIService.ExecQuery _
("Select * From Win32_Product Where Name = 'QuickTime'")

If colItems.Count = 0 Then
Wscript.Echo "QuickTime is not installed on this computer."
Else
For Each objItem in colItems
    Wscript.Echo "QuickTime version: " & objItem.Version
Next
End If
```

Please let me know how to find out the version of quick time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by adding a reference to `Microsoft WMI Scripting V1.2 Library` in your project.

Then you'll need to import these namespaces at the top of your code page:

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices
Imports WbemScripting
```

Here's an example:

```
Private Sub CheckVersion()

    Dim service As SWbemServicesEx = Nothing
    Dim collection As SWbemObjectSet = Nothing
    Dim item As SWbemObjectEx = Nothing

    Try

        Dim strComputer As String = "."
        Dim version As String = Nothing

        service = DirectCast(GetObject(String.Concat("winmgmts:\\", strComputer, "\root\cimv2")), SWbemServicesEx)
        collection = service.ExecQuery("Select * From Win32_Product Where Name = 'QuickTime'")

        If ((collection Is Nothing) OrElse (collection.Count = 0)) Then
            MessageBox.Show("QuickTime is not installed on this computer", Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
        Else
            For i As Integer = 0 To (collection.Count - 1)
                item = DirectCast(collection.ItemIndex(i), SWbemObjectEx)
                version = item.Properties_.Item("Version").Value.ToString()
                MessageBox.Show(String.Concat("QuickTime version: ", version), Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
            Next
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Me.Text, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error)
    Finally
        If (Not Object.ReferenceEquals(item, Nothing)) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(item)
        If (Not Object.ReferenceEquals(collection, Nothing)) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(collection)
        If (Not Object.ReferenceEquals(service, Nothing)) Then Marshal.ReleaseComObject(service)
    End Try

End Sub
```

**Update**

In the newest version the name is changed to `QuickTime 7`.

So you need to change your query:

From `Name = 'QuickTime'` to `Name Like 'QuickTime%'`.

Comment: This is not working with the latest version of quicktime. Just wondering what have they changed..

Comment: What is the exact version number?